# Hibernate delete many to many relation of not directly related entity

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Lets say I have a class A, which has a manyToMany relation to class B

And a class C which has a manyToMany relation to class B

how would I delete an instance of A, deleting all instances of B (including those who are shared with C) but not the C object?

A and C are NOT directly related though B, although every B has one A and 0...n Cs.

```
public class A {
  @Id
  @Column
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
  private String id;

  @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  private List<B> bs;
}

public class B {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "SEQUENCE")
  private Long id;
}

public class C {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "SEQUENCE")
  private Long id;

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private List<B> bs;
}
```

My first intuition was to simply `aRepository.deleteById(aId)` and let the cascade do some magic but that resulted in an `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails` error for `C -> C_B`

So I tried to walk through all Cs:

```
@Transactional // otherwise method would not have a transaction for 'remove' call
public void deleteA(aId) {
  A a = aRepository.findById(aId);
  List<C> cs = cRepository.findAll();

  for(B b: a.getBs()) {
    for(C c: cs) {
      // pretty sure there's a better way to do that...
      int index = c.getBs().stream().map(x -> x.getId()).collect(Collectors.toList()).indexOf(b.getId());

      if (index == -1) { continue; }
      c.getBs().remove(index);
      cRepository.save(c);
    }
  }

 a.deleteById(aId);
}
```

Unfortunately same error: `java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails`

Strangely it seems that sometimes refreshing my frontend page (or restarting the server) seemd to solve the issue although i have certain As where it never helps.

[image: example paint]

Comment: `cRepository.save(c)` is actually not deleting `C_B` rows from DB, spring/hibernate postpones delete op on commit phase, moreover, it tends to reorder DB operations, try adding `cRepository.flush()` before `a.deleteById(aId)`

Comment: Thanks I am not 100% sure if that was my only issue. I also had multiple C_B relations on the same C (and B) which further complicated things. But I'm now using save on A and saveAndFlush on C before deleting B, and this appears to be working